# Divisibility of number of derangements $D(n)$ by $n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As in the title, I'm looking for a proof or counterexample as to whether $D(n),$ the number of derangements of $n$ things, is always divisible by $n-1.$ It is for $n \le 30,$ but my software isn't reliable enough for a higher search.

If so, I'm also interested in  whether $D(n)/(n-1)$ must be odd.

Comment: [One of the recurrences for the derangement numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923868/derangements-recurrence) is $D\left(n\right) = \left(n-1\right) \left(D\left(n-1\right) + D\left(n-2\right)\right)$. Thence your divisibility. As for the oddness, that's true as well, and you can prove this by induction using the very same recurrence (since $\left(n-1\right) \cdot \left(\text{something odd}\right) + \left(n-2\right) \cdot \left(\text{something odd}\right)$ must be odd).

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'd accept that if it were an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me combine your two claims:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. Then, $D\left(n\right) = \left(n-1\right) a_n$ for some odd integer $a_n$.

Here, $D\left(n\right)$ denotes the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) (i.e., permutations with no fixed points) of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$.

This is easily proven by induction using one of the well-known recurrences for the derangement numbers (which has been proven many times on m.se: e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923868/derangements-recurrence) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679426/prove-by-induction-that-the-number-of-derangements-of-length-n-is-d-n-n-1)):

> **Theorem 2.** We have $D\left(n\right) = \left(n-1\right) \left(D\left(n-1\right) + D\left(n-2\right)\right)$ for all $n \geq 2$.

Now, we can prove Theorem 1:

*Proof of Theorem 1.* We proceed by strong induction on $n$.
Thus, we fix a nonnegative integer $m$.
We assume (as induction hypothesis) that Theorem 1 holds for all $n < m$.
We must prove that Theorem 1 holds for $n = m$.
In other words, we must prove that $D\left(m\right) = \left(m-1\right) a_m$ for some odd integer $a_m$.

If $m = 0$, then this is obvious (since $D\left(0\right) = 1 = \left(0-1\right) \left(-1\right)$ for the odd integer $-1$).
If $m = 1$, then this is also obvious (since $D\left(1\right) = 0 = \left(1-1\right) \cdot 1$ for the odd integer $1$).
Thus, we WLOG assume that $m \neq 0$ and $m \neq 1$.
Hence, $m \geq 2$, so that $m-2$ is a nonnegative integer satisfying $m-2 < m$.
Hence, our induction hypothesis shows that Theorem 1 holds for $n = m-2$.
In other words, $D\left(m-2\right) = \left(\left(m-2\right)-1\right) a_{m-2}$ for some odd integer $a_{m-2}$. Consider this $a_{m-2}$.
Also, $m \geq 2 \geq 1$. Hence, $m-1$ is a nonnegative integer satisfying $m-1 < m$.
Hence, our induction hypothesis shows that Theorem 1 holds for $n = m-1$.
In other words, $D\left(m-1\right) = \left(\left(m-1\right)-1\right) a_{m-1}$ for some odd integer $a_{m-1}$. Consider this $a_{m-1}$.

We have $a_{m-1} \equiv 1 \mod 2$ (since $a_{m-1}$ is odd);
hence, $D\left(m-1\right) = \left(\left(m-1\right)-1\right) \underbrace{a_{m-1}}_{\equiv 1 \mod 2} \equiv \left(m-1\right)-1 = m-2 \mod 2$.

We have $a_{m-2} \equiv 1 \mod 2$ (since $a_{m-2}$ is odd);
hence, $D\left(m-2\right) = \left(\left(m-2\right)-1\right) \underbrace{a_{m-2}}_{\equiv 1 \mod 2} \equiv \left(m-2\right)-1 = m-3 \mod 2$.

Now,
\begin{align}
\underbrace{D\left(m-1\right)}_{\equiv m-2 \mod 2} + \underbrace{D\left(m-2\right)}_{\equiv m-3 \mod 2}
\equiv \left(m-2\right) + \left(m-3\right) = 2m-5 \equiv -5 \equiv 1 \mod 2.
\end{align}
In other words, the integer $D\left(m-1\right) + D\left(m-2\right)$ is odd.

Now, Theorem 2 (applied to $n = m$) yields
\begin{align}
D\left(m\right)
&= \left(m-1\right) \left(D\left(m-1\right) + D\left(m-2\right) \right) .
\end{align}
Hence, $D\left(m\right) = \left(m-1\right) a_m$ for some odd integer $a_m$
(namely, for $a_m = D\left(m-1\right) + D\left(m-2\right)$).
In other words, Theorem 1 holds for $n = m$.
This completes the induction step, and with it the proof of Theorem 1. $\blacksquare$